# Downgrade PHP from 5.6 to 5.5 on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: php, ubuntu, version, php-5.5, downgrade

I'm trying to downgrade PHP version from 5.6 to 5.5 on Ubuntu 16.10.

After all the research I've done, [the main repository](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) from Ondrej, 
does not include 5.5 version anymore. none of the other repositories I try'ing to install contain PHP 5.5.

Does anyone know a solution for this?
Tnx

Comment: compile it from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to downgrade your ubuntu or else you need to use php 7, php 5.5 is outdated for ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Check my question. ondrej/php does not include php5.5 anymore.
For each one of the package's im trying to install, I get the error:
`E: Unable to locate package php5.5-X`

Comment: you need to downgrade your ubuntu or else you need to use php 7, php 5.5 is outdated for ubuntu 16.04

Comment: If you can update your answer I'll upvote for it,
Thank you very much!